# Difference between 'yy' and 'YY' in Java Time Pattern

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat

From document [SimpleDateTimePattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `yy` should be the same with `YY`.

Today is `Dec 30, 2019`, now we get `YY` for today is `20`, `yy` for today is `19`. What's the difference between `yy` and `YY` in Java Time Pattern?

Comment: I would suggest to use `java.time` API instead of legacy library

Comment: @YCF_L The difference between `y` and `Y` also applies to the [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes I know that, I put that comment to the OP to avoid using the legacy library.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`yy` is the calendar year, while `YY` is a week year. A week year can be different from the calendar year depending on which day the first of January falls. For example see [ISO-8601 week year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

Today (30 December 2019) is a good example, the calendar year is 2019, but the week year is 2020, because this week is week 1 of 2020. So `yy` will result in `19`, while `YY` results in `20`.

The definition of the first week of a year from the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

> The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the Gregorian
>   year's first Thursday in it. The following definitions based on
>   properties of this week are mutually equivalent, since the ISO week
>   starts with Monday:
>
> - It is the first week with a majority (4 or more) of its days in January.
> - Its first day is the Monday nearest to 1 January.
> - It has 4 January in it. Hence the earliest possible first week extends from Monday 29 December (previous Gregorian year) to Sunday 4
>     January, the latest possible first week extends from Monday 4 January
>     to Sunday 10 January.
> - It has the year's first working day in it, if Saturdays, Sundays and 1 January are not working days.
>
> If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in
>   week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, it is part of week 53 of the
>   previous year. If it is on a Saturday, it is part of the last week of
>   the previous year which is numbered 52 in a common year and 53 in a
>   leap year. If it is on a Sunday, it is part of week 52 of the previous
>   year.

Some locales, like for example the US, don't follow ISO-8601, because there they use Sunday as the first day of the week, but they have similar rules for week years.

Answer (score 4):

You have it in you link:

> y  **Year**    Year    1996; 96
>
> Y  **Week year**   Year    2009; 09

**Week year** can be different, for example this new year week, than current year

[Week year](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeknumbers) defines as **year's first Thursday**:

> The first week of the year is the week that contains that year's first Thursday

Answer (score 2):

> They both represent a year but yyyy represents the calendar year while
>   YYYY represents the year of the week.

An example illustrates this much better than words ever could.

```
package datetest;    

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String[] dates = {"2018-12-01", "2018-12-31", "2019-01-01"};
            for (String date: dates) {
                SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date d = dt.parse(date);

                SimpleDateFormat dtYYYY = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY");
                SimpleDateFormat dtyyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

                System.out.println("For date :" + date + " the YYYY year is : " + dtYYYY.format(d) + " while for yyyy it's " + dtyyyy.format(d));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed with exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
For date : 2018-12-01 the YYYY year is : 2018 while for yyyy it's 2018
For date : 2018-12-31 the YYYY year is : 2019 while for yyyy it's 2018
For date : 2019-01-01 the YYYY year is : 2019 while for yyyy it's 2019
```