# problem with SimpleDateFormatter at end of year

Tags: java

Please take a look at the following code:

```
    Date date = new GregorianCalendar (2019, Calendar.DECEMBER, 30).getTime (); 
    System.out.println (date);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd.MM.YYYY");
    System.out.println (formatter.format (date));
```

The output is as follow:

```
Mon Dec 30 00:00:00 CET 2019
30.12.2020
```

Look at the year. What is wrong?

Same problem with '2019-12-31' while '2019-12-29' is ok.

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: Hi Tombo, it's time to use  LocalDate  :)

Comment: Possibly related: [Difference between 'yy' and 'YY' in Java Time Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59527605/6395627). Though I highly recommend using the `java.time` API added in Java 8.

Comment: Ha!  I ran into the same issue last week!